# Hibernate: How to start a single test from the Hibernate test suite?

Tags: java, hibernate, junit, gradle

Hibernate has its own test infrastructure, that can be used to test Hibernate and its various dialects.

The infrastructure is based on JUnit (the Tests) and Gradle (automation of the test process).

More on it you can find here:

- https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-matrix-testing
- https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/wiki/Hibernate-JUnit-Infastructure

You can start all tests from the test suite using `gradle`:

```
gradle hibernate-core:matrix_mysql51
```

In this case all tests of the `hibernate-core` module will be started.
There are more than 4000 tests in the module.

I would like to start only some of them.

How do it do it?
Is it possible to use the same testing infrastructure, but start single tests from the testsuite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
gradle hibernate-core:matrix_mysql51 -Dmatrix_mysql51.single=annotations/EntityTest
```

Comment: Brilliant!! It works indeed! Could I may be choose a group of tests? For example all tests in `annotations`?

Comment: yes, it's possible using wildcards, see gradle java plugin [documentation](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#N127CC)